# How can I make mvn checkstyle check if all my javadoc comment's contents start with an uppercase?

Tags: maven-2, comments, design-patterns, javadoc, checkstyle

I'd like to have my checkstyle configured so that it verifies all my javadoc comments start with an upper case letter:

```
/** 
 * Hello
```

Where can I set that up? I think I'll have to enable checkstyle on comments first but I'm not sure how.

And then how do I set up a filter that checks for the occurence of `\/\*\*` and then ensures a `\s*\*\s[A-Z]+` follows?

**EDIT:** 
If What I need is not supported by checkstyle at the moment: How do I set up my own checkstyle modul and include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Checkstyle does not support what you want to get (as I know). But the process to do that should be the following:

- Add the checkstyle maven plugin `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin` to your Maven2 POM.
- Create a checkstyle configuration that includes the rules that you want to have.
- Reference that configuration in your POM as `configLocation`.

Checkstyle supports as rules for classes and style:

- Check empty JavaDoc
- Check first sentence (that it exist)
- Check end of sentence (but not begin)

What you can do (in the long run) is to expand checkstyle, and to give your enhancement to the community, so it may be integrated into Checkstyle itself and the Maven plugin for Checkstyle. Have a look at ["Extending Checkstyle"](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), it is not so difficult, I have done that on my own. See for an example the implementation of [Checkstyle JavaDoc Style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html). The difficult part is to put that in the project, and get it everywhere you will need it: Maven, Eclipse, NetBeans, Sonar, ...

Comment: Hm, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly that didn't provide any new information. I have checkstyle setup and customized. It's just our internal requirement to start all comments with an uppercase as it is a sentence and should be read as such in a javadoc. 
So basicly what I need to do is figure out how to create my own checkstyle filter and load it with the other modules or wait for checkstyle to include something like that? 


Maybe someone else knows more..? Especially about creating my own checkstyle modules and including them.